# jQuery file uploader - Django not working correctly with chunks

Tags: python, django, file-upload, jquery-file-upload, chunking

I've spent some days by now trying to figure out how to tell Django that my [jQuery file uploader](http://aquantum-demo.appspot.com/file-upload) is sending chunks and not x seperate files.

I know that I need a custom `FileUploadHandler` like here [in this one](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/678/).

My client-side code is posted [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17238894/1331671).

The plugin sends chunk by chunk as a separate AJAX call (at least with FireBug it looks like this). The server accepts every one of them and saves them under a different name (in my case "_1", "_2", "_3"... ). And yes, the handler is used. I proved it via `print`

BTW: The `Content-Range` in the header is correct.

BTW II: [This plugin](https://github.com/sigurdga/django-jquery-file-upload) unfortunately did not utilize chunking... so no solution here for me.

So, has anybody an idea what I might be doing wrong? I found some other `FileUploadHandlers` but they all seem pretty similar. So I guess the problem is not here?

Comment: Need more details, the part that distinguishes the first chunk from the consequent ones is on a server-side, so you need to check this logic in views.py.
So, we need to see the method that receives chunks.

Comment: You do know that the post is 8 years old? :D

Comment: Yeah! Not initially, but later I decided to leave the comment.
So, if there is a way to develop it into a helpful example, it would be... okay... funny, yet useful.